# Is there an established name for long scrolling web pages?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

Is there a name for very long scrolling web pages like the [Android KitKat page](http://www.android.com/kitkat/)? I am trying to Google for CSS tutorials and other examples, but have no idea what the design is called.

Comment: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/

Firefox OS uses a similar design. I wonder what the design is called as well.

Comment: The signal to noise ratio of that page is awful.

Comment: @whatsisname I don't disagree, but have seen the pattern show up more and more frequently. Wanted to put a name to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[These guys](http://digualized.com/design-trends-of-2013-the-layered-site/) call it a *layered site* or *sandwich site*:

> websites containing clear and concise sections layered on top of each other.

I prefer this term over "Parallax scrolling" since parallax scrolling is more associated with multi-layer horizontal scrolling that creates the illusion of depth to the viewer. (Background moves slower than foreground, it's the same effect when looking out of a car window)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it referred to as *single-page design* or a *single-page website*. For the specific kind you are talking about, I would use the term *scrolling single-page website*.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application
- http://www.awwwards.com/websites/single-page/

Answer (score 0):

When it's the only page on the website - as is the case in the example you mentioned - the term *one-pager* probably fits best.

As for multi-page websites with long pages, I wouldn't call them anything else than *page* or *long page* :)

Answer (score -1):

Parallax Scrolling

Here's a link to some of the great example of Parallax Scrolling websites.

http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html

Comment: well, no. parallax scrolling creates the illusion of depth by moving the foreground slower than the background(s), while the Android-Kitkat page is simply scrolling to the different parts on click

Comment: @DonL. Actually, the android page does use parallax scrolling, although it is more subtle (the doughnuts move slightly, for example).

Comment: @Brendon I think it somehow _works_ similar (with layers), but I wouldn't call it parallax scrolling, since the (at least my) mind is not tricked into the depth-effect. this is - probably - because it's not scrolling horizontallay

Comment: to correct my first comment: the background is of course moving _slower_ than the foreground